# Trouble with React Hooks, which react hook rule am I breaking?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am receiving this error:

> Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component.

I am using a hook to grab the router location with the function `HeaderView()` (which alone works fine) and setting state so that I can play around with my components based on the current route.

Here is the composition of my hook:

```
const Navbar = () => {
  const [route, setRoute] = useState("/");


  function HeaderView() {
    let location = useLocation();
    console.log(location.pathname);
    setRoute(location.pathname);
    return;
  }

  useEffect(() => {
   HeaderView()
  }, [route]);

.. rest of the component.
```

useLocation is a function provided by "react-router-dom";
Everytime I think I have a handle on hooks, there seems to be something else that trips me up, so frustration, thanks for reading.

Comment: the solution is in the error , move `useLocation` to the body of `Navbar`  ... `const Navbar = () => {   let location = useLocation() ...`

Comment: @Chiller can you explain why that makes a difference here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What happens if you unwrap `HeaderView`?

```
const Navbar = () => {
const [route, setRoute] = useState("/");
let location = useLocation();

useEffect(() => {
    console.log(location.pathname);
    setRoute(location.pathname);
}, [location]);

.. rest of the component.
```

#### [Only Call Hooks at the Top Level](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html#only-call-hooks-at-the-top-level)

> **Don’t call Hooks inside loops, conditions, or nested functions.** Instead, always use Hooks at the top level of your React function. By following this rule, you ensure that Hooks are called in the same order each time a component renders. That’s what allows React to correctly preserve the state of Hooks between multiple `useState` and `useEffect` calls.

Note: Also, be careful of infinite loops in `useEffect`.

Comment: Yes that works, but why does that work? doesn't useLocation only get run once? (the result is that it updates on every change of route, but that's confusing

Comment: You were calling it inside of useEffect which breaks a rule of hooks `Call them at the top level in the body of a function component.`

Comment: So I don't even need useEffect, right? I am already achieving my goal by accessing location in my component instead of route from state, it's exactly the same ?

Comment: I'm not sure what your motivation is to hold the location in state, but it seems like you have what you need already from `useLocation`, without storing it again in local state when it updates.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're seeing that error because you're calling the hook inside useEffect.

```
Do not call Hooks inside functions passed to useMemo, useReducer, or useEffect.
```

source: https://reactjs.org/warnings/invalid-hook-call-warning.html

Comment: I think you are right, as useLocation is a router hook afterall. But that really confuses me as I thought hooks were just functions called when a component updates

Answer (score 1):

One of the rules for hooks is that they cannot be called **inside loops**, **conditions**, or **nested functions**. Instead, always use Hooks at the **top level** of your React function.

https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html

There is a good article, which explained the concept of how hooks were implemented thanks to closure. I enjoyed reading it and it helped me understand better  how it works under the hood

https://www.netlify.com/blog/2019/03/11/deep-dive-how-do-react-hooks-really-work/