# Using hooks inside custom hooks

Tags: javascript, react-native, graphql, apollo-client

I am a beginner to react-native and I have been trying to fetch data using apollo client's useQuery hook. I have written 3 custom hooks, the way they are calling each other is shown below(in api.tsx). Every time I make a call, I get the `Hooks can only be called inside the body of a function component.` error. I am attaching my code snippet here. I am hiding the extra code and showing the part from where the error is thrown. I tried using the hint from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76158527/how-to-call-hooks-inside-custom-hooks-getting-this-error-invalid-hook-call) solution, but the error still persists.
Any help will be appreciated.

Login.tsx

```
import { Image, Pressable, Text, View } from 'react-native'
import { useShopifyLogin } from '../../api/api';
//....other imports

const Login = (props:any) => {
    const nav = useNavigation();
    const [email,setEmail] = useState('');
    const [password,setPassword] = useState('');
    const [showPassword,setShowPassword] = useState(false);

    return (......
            <Button 
                buttonStyle={[styles.loginButton]}
                radius={20}
                disabled = {email !== '' ? password !== '' ? false:true:true}
                title={'Log In'}
                disabledTitleStyle={{fontSize:16}}
                onPress={()=> {
                    let userInfo = useShopifyLogin({username:email,password:password});
                    console.log(userInfo);
                    if(userInfo !== undefined){
                        nav.goBack();
                    }
                }}
            />
            ....
    )
}

export default Login
```

api.tsx

```
import { useQuery } from "@apollo/client";
import * as query from './shopify_query';
import Loader from "../components/Loader/Loader";

export const useShopifyLogin = ({username, password}) => {
    try {
        var accessToken = useCreateAccessToken(username = username, password = password);
        var userInfo = useGetUserInfo({accessToken: accessToken});
        return userInfo;
    } catch (error:any) {
        throw new Error(error.toString());
    }
}

const useCreateAccessToken = (username:string,password:string) => {
    const queryString = query.CREATE_CUSTOMER_TOKEN; //gql query defined in a separate file
    const {loading,error,data} = useQuery(
        queryString.query,{
        variables: {
            ...queryString.variables,'email': username,'password': password,
            fetchPolicy:'network-only',
        }
    })
    if (loading){
        console.log('Loading')
    }
    if (error) {
        throw new Error(error.toString());
    }
    var json = data.data['customerAccessTokenCreate']['customerAccessToken'];
    console.log(json);
    return json['accessToken'];
}

const useGetUserInfo = ({accessToken}) => {
    console.log('::::request getUserInfo');
    const queryString = query.GET_CUSTOMER_INFO; //gql query defined in a separate file
    const {loading,error,data} = useQuery(
        queryString.query,
        {
            variables:{...queryString.variables,accessToken:accessToken}
        }
    )
    if (loading){
        return Loader
    }
    if (error) {
        throw new Error(error.toString());
    }
    var user = data;
    return user;
}
```

Comment: You're using the `useShopifyLogin` hook inside the `onPress` callback, which isn't a render function. Also, what Jared said.

Comment: In addition to that hooks **must** be called unconditionally, which means you can't call them in a `try/catch`. For the same reason it is a mistake to `throw` in your custom hooks, so don't do that. This is all very clearly spelled out in [the documentation](https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Trouble with React Hooks, which react hook rule am I breaking?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61333484/trouble-with-react-hooks-which-react-hook-rule-am-i-breaking)

Comment: @DustInComp I want to implement login functionality. That is why I need to get the user details only when the Log In Button is hit. That is another reason why I am confused about using the hook at top level. Any guidance on how can I implement your solution? Thanks

Comment: @KhushalSonawat if you only want to call certain functionality in response to a user action, define those functions as regular imperative callbacks, not custom hooks. Just replace `useQuery` with `fetch` calls.

Comment: @JaredSmith I guess yes. I want to use the hook only when the button is hit which is a condition. But the reason why I'm stuck at this problem is due to the usage of useQuery hook of apollo. Otherwise, I'd be again setting up the whole network requests once again

Comment: @KhushalSonawat I see, it's GraphQL, I'm not familiar with Apollo but it looks like you can set up an imperative callback with [`useLazyQuery`](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/data/queries/#manual-execution-with-uselazyquery)